# Tag synonym request: [trenched] → [iron-brigade]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

*Trenched* by Double Fine [is going to be renamed](http://www.xblafans.com/trenched-to-become-iron-brigade-everywhere-dlc-to-come-25910.html) *Iron Brigade*. I'd like to request that [trenched](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trenched) be made a synonym of [iron-brigade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-brigade) when the update goes live later this month (September 2011).

Answer (score 1):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)